# Improving the performance of code

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

```
int original,dp[100001][2048],arr[100001];
cin>>original;
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
cin>>arr[i];
dp[0][original]=1;
for(int i=1; i<100000; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=1024; j++)
    {
        dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j]+dp[i-1][j^arr[i]];
    }
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this simple code for finding that there are how many total combinations of array elements which can compute XOR value with variable original equals 1023.

Comment: The first step to performance improvement is to know what you're trying to accomplish. So far you haven't shared that with us.

Comment: Well, you added some info, but it didn't help me much:(  'arr' seems to be uninitialized?

Comment: Also, to know what's `n` would help.

Comment: @skypjack sorry for inconvinience. I edited the code.

Comment: @wridhiman please, post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this snippet is full of errors.

Comment: I think people are here to just vote down. Not to give solution.

Comment: Since your code has UB, it can be optimised to `{}`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What does that means.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, you are asking for this thing

```
   for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       occurence[arr[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
       if(occurence[i]!=0)
       {
           tt_ways[i]=power(2,occurence[i]-1);
       }
       else
       {
           tt_ways[i]=0;
       }
    }
    dp[0][original]=1;
    if(tt_ways[0]!=0)
    {
        answer[0][tt]=tt_ways[0]+tt_ways[0];
    }
   for(int i=1; i<1024; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<1024; j++)
        {
            const long long int temp =(tt_ways[i]*dp[i-1][j])%MOD;
            if(tt_ways[i]==0)
            {
                dp[i][j]=(dp[i-1][j])%MOD;
            }
            else
            {
                dp[i][j]=(dp[i][j] + temp)%MOD;
                dp[i][j^i]=(dp[i][j^i] + temp)%MOD;
            }
        }
    }
  cout<<dp[1023][0];
```